# Mark email as read using imap protocol Tcpclient

Tags: c#, email, imap, tcpclient

```
_imapSw.WriteLine("$ STATUS INBOX (unseen)");
_imapSw.WriteLine("$ SELECT INBOX");
_imapSw.Flush();
```

After getting email count of unseen.I want to mark email as read. Please tell me command to mark first email as read.
`

_imapSw.WriteLine("$ FETCH " + index + " (body[header.fields (from subject date)])");
 _imapSw.WriteLine("$ FETCH " + index + " body[text]");`

i can fetch email header and body but this is not marking email as read.

Comment: Could you show us more your code?

Comment: `public int MailUnreadCount()
{
    _imapSw.WriteLine("$ STATUS INBOX (unseen)");
    _imapSw.Flush();

    string res = Response();
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    Match m = Regex.Match(res, "[0-9]*[0-9]");
    return Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString());
}` public void SelectInbox()
`{
    _imapSw.WriteLine("$ SELECT INBOX");
    _imapSw.Flush();
    Response();
}`i need command of imap to mark seen flag

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting the inbox, you get the ID of the first unread/unseen mail.

```
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft NonJunk $Junk Junk $MDNSent $F
orwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft NonJunk $Junk Jun
k $MDNSent $Forwarded \*)] Flags permitted.
* 8421 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 3395] First unseen.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 47932578432] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 46214] Predicted next UID
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1377] Highest
```

Then you can use the store command to mark it as read:

```
_imapSw.WriteLine("$ STORE 3395 +flags \\seen");
_imapSw.Flush();
```

Comment: it's worked great. i was just changed to \\seen.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I have fixed it in my answer now.